# An algorithm that can handle these queries

Tags: algorithm, multiset

**Query type 1**:
Asking the kth less frequent (less occurring) number in the multiset. When there are more than one possible answers, return the biggest one.

For the multiset = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3} and k = 3, the answer is 2.

freq(1) = 1, freq(3) = 2, freq(2) = 3; so the 3rd less frequent is 2.

**Query type 2**:
Adding an integer x to the multiset.

**Query type 3**:
Deleting an integer x from the multiset.

Query type 1 is the most frequent query.

**I need an algorithm that can handle these queries with its complexity better or equal to O(sqrt N) per query where N is the current size of multiset.**

Comment: A balanced binary search tree covers cases 2 and 3 in `O(lgN)` time.  Not sure about the performance of finding the kth least element.

Comment: I'm most concerned here with the misuse of the word *set*. Sets, by definition, don't contain duplicates (at least, when used with the type of rigor that one would expect given the rest of this question setup)

Comment: I meant multiset, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can take a hash table and store the frequency of every number. Then we need a self-balanced search tree having a key in the form of a pair `(frequency(number), number)`.

Query 1. Search for a kth element in a self-balanced search tree in `O(log(n))`.
Query 2 and 3. Change the frequency in a hash table in `O(1)`, then update-key operation in a tree (or pair of delete/insert operations) in `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Yeah of course, but this not one data structure, which is what the OP wants IMHO. If I am wrong, then voilà!

Comment: @gsamaras, actually he needs two indices: one ordered index on frequencies and one unordered index on values. I suppose all multi-index data structures consist of several less complex data structures.

Comment: It looks like there is no data structure for this. This will do my job after small modifications.